# How to set Spring profile from system variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles

I have a Spring project which uses another project. Each project has its own spring profile initialize from java code using `applicationContext.xml` and `*.properties` for each profile. I inject the profile from `args[]`. **The problem is that second project uses the default configuration for the env from the** `applicationContext.xml`
I can not inject the env from `args[]` to the second project and I tried looking for an article which will explain how Spring profile works.

1. Is there a hierarchy on which it will look the profile when default is not configured at `applicationContext.xml` ?
2. Is System var stronger than `applicationContext.xml` configuration?
3. What you think is the best solution to my challenge?

Articles on that subject or even examples would be most appreciated.

Comment: Not to future readers: requests for learning resources other than ones from "official sources" (official documentation, etc) are not allowed because they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam (see the [help/on-topic]).

Answer (score 214):

SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE is the environment variable to override/pick Spring profile

Comment: Along with Docker also works well with TypeSafe config (HOCON) library, Shell script to initialize app/system/Docker container etc.

Comment: reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles

Answer (score 93):

If you provide your JVM the Spring profile there should be no problems:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=development -jar yourApplication.jar
```

Also see Spring-Documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

> **69.5 Set the active Spring profiles**
>
> The Spring Environment has an API for this, but normally you would set
>   a System property (spring.profiles.active) or an OS environment
>   variable (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE). E.g. launch your application with a
>   -D argument (remember to put it before the main class or jar archive):
>
> $ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production
>   demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> In Spring Boot you can also set the active profile in
>   application.properties, e.g.
>
> spring.profiles.active=production
>
> A value set this way is replaced by the System property or environment
>   variable setting, but not by the SpringApplicationBuilder.profiles()
>   method. Thus the latter Java API can be used to augment the profiles
>   without changing the defaults.
>
> See Chapter 25, Profiles in the ‘Spring Boot features’ section for
>   more information.

Answer (score 56):

I normally configure the applicationContext using **Annotation based configuration** rather than **XML based configuration**. Anyway, I believe both of them have the **same priority**.

*Answering your question, system variable has higher priority *

---

### Getting profile based beans from applicationContext

- ### Use @Profile on a Bean

```java
@Component
@Profile("dev")
public class DatasourceConfigForDev
```

Now, the profile is `dev`

Note : if the Profile is given as
        `@Profile("!dev")` then the profile will exclude dev and be for all others.

- ### Use profiles attribute in XML

```xml
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="DatasourceConfigForDev" class="org.skoolguy.profiles.DatasourceConfigForDev"/>
</beans>
```

---

### Set the value for profile:

- ### Programmatically via WebApplicationInitializer interface

  In web applications, WebApplicationInitializer can be used to configure the ServletContext programmatically

```java
@Configuration
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
    }
}
```

- ### Programmatically via ConfigurableEnvironment

  You can also set profiles directly on the environment:

```java
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    // ...

    env.setActiveProfiles("dev");
```

- ### Context Parameter in web.xml

  profiles can be activated in the web.xml of the web application as well, using a context parameter:

```xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

- ### JVM System Parameter

  The profile names passed as the parameter will be activated during application start-up:

  ```
  -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
  ```

  In IDEs, you can set the environment variables and values to use when an application runs. The following is the Run Configuration in Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse Run Configuration - screenshot is unavailable]

- ### Environment Variable

  to set via command line : `export spring_profiles_active=dev`

> Any bean that does not specify a profile belongs to “default” profile.

---

### The priority order is :

1. Context parameter in web.xml
2. WebApplicationInitializer
3. JVM System parameter
4. Environment variable

Comment: Do you have a reference for the priority order?

Answer (score 17):

If you are using docker to deploy the spring boot app, you can set the *profile* using the flag **e**:

> docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod" -p 8080:8080 -t
>   r.test.co/myapp:latest

Comment: how this flag used internally in spring.

Comment: @ParmarKamlesh flag `-e` is used to passed env variable inside docker container. Since, Spring reads `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` env var for getting active profile, docker's -e flag works.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the spring profile by supplying `-Dspring.profiles.active=<env>`

For java files in **source(src) directory**, you can use by 
`System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")`

For java files in **test directory** you can supply

- `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` to `<env>`

OR

Since, "environment", "jvmArgs" and "systemProperties" are ignored for the "test" task. In root `build.gradle` add a task to set jvm property and environment variable.

```
test {
    def profile = System.properties["spring.profiles.active"]
    systemProperty "spring.profiles.active",profile
    environment "SPRING.PROFILES_ACTIVE", profile
    println "Running ${project} tests with profile: ${profile}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to set the environment variable as `spring.profiles.active=development`. So that all applications running in that machine will refer the variable and start the application. The order in which spring loads a properties as follows

```
application.properties
system properties
environment variable
```

Answer (score 2):

If i run the command line : `java -Dspring.profiles.active=development -jar yourApplication.jar`  from my webapplication directory it states that the path is incorrect. So i just defined the profile in manualy in the application.properties file like this :

```
spring.profiles.active=mysql
```

or

```
spring.profiles.active=postgres
```

or

```
spring.profiles.active=mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late to the party but here are the new trends for this topic: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/profile-specific-logging/

Here is a excellent example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
  <property name="LOG_FILE" value="c:/temp/spring.log}"/>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
  
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>
  
  <springProfile name="local | dev">
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>
    <root level="DEBUG">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
  </springProfile>
 
  <springProfile name="prod">
    <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
  </springProfile>
 
  <springProfile name="!local & !dev & !prod">
    <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
  </springProfile>
  
</configuration>
```

!NB! If you have problems using `&` replace it with `&amp;`

Comment: what filename is that blob of XML from?