# Setting profiles in Spring Boot application based on system property

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'd like to set active profile for Spring based on environment variable. To do so, I've written the following code:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBootApplicationInitializer
        implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {

        String platform = System.getProperty("platform");

        if ("prod".equals(platform)) {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active",
                                            "prod");
        } else if ("stag".equals(platform)) {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active",
                                            "stag");
        } else {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active",
                                            "dev");
        }
    }
}
```

This code gets executed, however, no profile is set as Spring writes:
    INFO - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520638/how-to-set-spring-profile-from-system-variable might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I achieve what I want?

You could simply set the desired profile in the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable.

---

> What if I don't want to set this variable for `dev` environment? Spring will not pick up active profile then.

To address your comment, there are a [number of ways](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) to configure Spring Boot applications. If your concern is not using this environment variable for development, you'll be please to know that you can still use a properties or YAML file for development.

Just bear in mind that OS environment variables take precedence over application properties (`application.properties` and YAML variants). For details all configuration property sources, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

Comment: Yes, of course. What if I don't want to set this variable for `dev` environment? Spring will not pick up active profile then.

Comment: @menteith You can still use a properties or YAML file for your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try like like this in application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${platform}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. After setting env variable, Spring prints  `The following profiles are active: ${platfrom}`

Comment: it works at my machine. i set variable in idea environment variable.. when deploy tomcat it reads from tomcat environment variable

Comment: i think u miss variable name. i gave platfrom . u used platform

Comment: @menteith did u check with variable name?

Comment: I did exactly what you described. Unfortunately, it didn't do the trick.

Comment: it can do a lots of way. i think it will also works. i said to check variable name. cause there is spelling mistake