# SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE does not work. How to fix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.properties-and-configuration) (and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46050490/147530)):

> The Spring Environment has an API for this, but you would normally set a System property (spring.profiles.active) or an OS environment variable (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE).

I am using version 2.7.3 of Spring Boot:

```
<dependency>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

We have a `src/main/resources/application.properties` file like this:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=local
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:teradata://TDTEST/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8
spring.datasource.password=
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=prod
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.url=
```

We built a fatjar using the maven shade plugin. But when we try to run it like this:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local java -ea -jar target/td-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

We get this message:

```
17:09:42.663 [main] INFO cdao.dpde.app.App - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
```

Why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can remember the problem in our case was a misconfigured `pom.xml` due to which the `.properties` file was not making it to the fat jar. There was no issue with the `.properties` file or with Spring. *The solution was to use the [`spring-boot-maven-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/) to package the application instead of the `shade` plugin*. `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>        
        </plugin>       
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your `application.yml/properties` to the following

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service-name

  profiles:
    active: ${PROFILE:local}
```

and run the following command

`java -jar td-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --PROFILE=environement`

the advantage of the above is you can default your profile to a fallback profile if the environment was not provided.

*The command above takes into consideration that you are inside of the /target dir*