# Set active profile in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an `application.yml` and `application-prod.yml`. I set my default values in the `application.yml` and override some values in the `application-prod.yml`.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
example: test
```

**application-prod.yml**

```
example: prod-example
```

When running my app "example" will have a value of "test" instead of "prod-example".

How do I correctly specify the profile in the `application.yml`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Spring profile from system variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520638/how-to-set-spring-profile-from-system-variable)

Comment: Almost. I'd found tutorials showing it being done by just using the configuration like I've shown so was hoping it could also be done this way?

Comment: maybe changing `active: prod` to `active: [prod]` could help?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying Unfortunately not. It doesn't seem to do anything. It's as though the property isn't even used. I've also tried using `spring.profiles.default`.

Answer (score 0):

we can create multiple profiles using "---" separator in single yaml property file too. Hope this helps!

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "dev"

---

spring:
  profiles: dev
example: test


---
spring:
  profiles: prod
example: prod-example
```

Answer (score 0):

set `application.yml`

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
example: it is de default ,if you not set -D
```

set `application-prod.yml`

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod
example: set -D = prod
```

run `java -jar xxx.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod`